# Is self-seal rubber k-flex safe for hot water pex pipe

Tags: plumbing, insulation, hot-water, pex

I ask because it seems the adhesive is melting and sticking to the pipe (see attached image). Is this okay? Should I instead use k-flex that isn't self-seal? Or maybe should I use a different insulation altogether (e.g., fiberglass)? Thank you for your help.

[image]

Edit in response to FreeMan’s suggestion, I have hydronic baseboard heaters where some sections of the circuit are exposed pex piping. I would like to insulate these sections to prevent unnecessary heat loss. I figured I would try rubber k-flex? What do you all suggest?

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking about your fix (which seems to be failing), tell us about the problem you're trying to solve.